# Study Error while plotting HTF engulfing candles on LTF chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am getting a study error:

> Objects positioned using xloc.bar_index cannot be drawn further than
> 500 bars into the future.

I have no idea where to even begin to fix this. Some help from experts here would be very helpful.

```
indicator('MTF Engulfing Candles', overlay=true, max_boxes_count=500, max_lines_count=500)

tf = input.timeframe("240", "Timeframe", options=["60","240","480","720","W","M"])

O1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, open[1])
H1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, high[1])        
L1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, low[1])          
C1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, close[1])

O2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, open[2])
H2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, high[2])        
L2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, low[2])          
C2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, close[2])

barIndex = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, bar_index)
barIndexMinus2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, bar_index-2)

// FUNCTIONS
bullE()=>
    r = C2 < O2 and C1 > O1 and C1 > H2 ? 1 : 0
    
bearE()=>
    r = C2 > O2 and C1 < O1 and C1 < L2 ? 1 : 0

if bullE()
    box.new(left=barIndexMinus2, right=barIndex, top=H1 ,bottom=math.min(L2,L1), border_color = color.new(color.black,65), bgcolor = color.new(#66bb6a,75))
    
if bearE()
    box.new(left=barIndexMinus2, right=barIndex, top=math.max(H2,H1) ,bottom=L2, border_color = color.new(color.black,65), bgcolor = color.new(#ffa726, 75))
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved it by using `bar_time` instead of `bar_index`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: See my answer to this question for a link to the rationale behind why this works.

Answer (score 2):

You are requesting `bar_index` from other timeframes, and you use this as `left` and `right` parameters of the `box.new()`. The problem is, this difference might be quite a lot depending on the timeframe you are on.

For example, on BINANCE:BTCUSDT, 1h, current `bar_index` is `23426`. `barIndex` and `barIndexMinus2` are `11051` and `11049` respectively.

You see, if you use those variables as `left` and `right` arguments of your `box.new()` call, it will cause this issue. Because the distance between the current bar index and your variables are more than 500.

Comment: you have any workaround in mind ?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do? Why are you using `bar_index` from other timeframes?

Comment: well i had an idea to be aware of htf engulfing candles while taking trades on ltf charts.  i have seen some indicators do this, but sadly their code is not open to view, so i have no idea how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

The following link contains a good explanation to what is gooing on (except it explains it in the context of the x coordinate of a label): https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/update-label-time/

I quote:

> When the label uses bar numbers for its time coordinate, then the `label.set_x()` function cannot move the label more than 500 bars in the future. If we try, Pine Script generates this error message: "objects positioned using xloc.bar_index cannot be drawn further than 500 bars into the future". The same error message happens when we give label.set_x() a time value while the label uses bar numbers.

The link contains their take on to fix it; I quote:

> To fix that issue, we give `label.set_x()` a bar number instead. Or, if we want to use time values, switch the label to time values first with the `label.set_xloc()` function. Labels have no limitations with previous (historical) bars. The `label.set_x()` function can use both bar numbers and time values to place the label on any previous bar.

This reasoning applies to other objects you draw via specifying their x coodinate.